# "edit" link to edit your subscription to Favorite tags does not work

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, email-notification, subscription

When I want to edit my subscription to "Favorite" tags, the small "edit" link under my email does nothing.

I click on it and nothing happends.

I've tried with Firefox and with Google Chrome and same thing.

So at this point I am not able to change how frequently I get the emails.

Relevant link for my user is: https://stackexchange.com/filters/117740/favorite-tags

And I get there when I click on "advanced tag subscription".

**UPDATE**

I have added an image since it seems is not clear what I am talking about:

http://softconsultant.ro/images/bug-edit-link-not-clickable.png

Comment: @Skliwz this was already reported, Ben even marked the other one as planned but never replied when I asked about progress. Is the bug still planned for a fix?